# Move Browser window down to the position of a div when it is loaded by ajax & Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser, html, move

I have a div into which I am loading data dynamically by ajax, jquery. like

```
$('#wp').load('http://someurl.com/getit',p,function(str){} );
```

Now because I am having page full of data before that div I need to move the browser window down to that div's location after it is loaded with slow motion like the similar effects in stackoverflow. Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this plugin: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

After you've loaded your content into the DIV, call

$.scrollTo("#your-div-id-here", {duration: 1000 });

duration is in milliseconds for the scroll animation.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am really able to use that with hell lot of ease.
Thanks again